# Popen call not outputting to a file or determining the parameter string correctly in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, popen

The two Popen commands run below the strings are identical yet only the second one works when I input the whole command that I run in terminal. The first one I can see the ghostscript command run as it pops up even though with -q it isn't supposed to but the output isn't generated anywhere as far as I can tell. The second case no window pops open but it outputs to output.pdf just as it should.

In the input the first argument is the name of the output file and any prior argument is the input pdf files.

Does anyone know what is going on??

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import os
import sys
output = sys.argv[1]
cwd = os.getcwd()
cmd = ['gs', '-q', '-dNOPAUSE','-dBATCH', '-sDECIVE=pdfwrite', '-sOutputFile='+str(output)]
for i in range(2,len(sys.argv)): # appends all input pdfs at the end to be arguments
    cmd.append(sys.argv[i])
#a = Popen(cmd) # Done originally but didn't work either
a = Popen(' '.join(cmd), shell=True)
a.wait()
a = Popen('gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf input1.pdf input2.pdf', shell=True)
a.wait()
```

Comment: Why do you have `shell=True`? You shouldn't. And you should pass a list instead of a joined string.

Comment: Pretty sure the strings are not identical, there are a lot of filenames in the second one

Comment: @ThomasFenzl I guess everything after the dirname is equal to `output` variable. The path is prepended to a huge string with a number of files. But of course it's difficult to confirm, since we don't see the variables values.

Comment: @kirelagin You're right, I've missed the for loop

Comment: @kirelagin - That is what I did originally and it did not work properly either so I tried doing it with Shell=True.

Comment: @ThomasFenzl - Yes that is correct. The first argument is the output file and any prior argument after is the input pdf files. I've tried updating the description better now. I don't know why it is blocking ghostscript from writing out to a file or terminating before it does this. I've wrote a script to turn pdfs gray with postscript in perl so I may see if that works in this case.

Comment: @kirelagin - Updated the code to show what I did originally. I passed the cmd list which is why I made the list in the first place with shell=False. The same result. That is when I tried running the command like the above and put shell=True just because I copied the string in the second one from a terminal command. I think it is either terminating before outputting or not getting all the input arguments correctly.

Comment: You've got a typo in your first command: `-sDECIVE` should be `-sDEVICE`. If that's only a typo in your example code but not in your real code, then that's not the problem -- but if that typo's in your real code, that is either your problem or part of your problem.

Comment: Also, the `-sOutputFile` part at the end should look like `'-sOutputFile='+str(output)`. Right now you're missing a single-quote and a `+` operator.

Comment: @rmunn - Thanks yep that was the problem. I had never noticed that. No I have the output file portion correct in the real code. If you post an answer I'll accept. Don't know how I didn't notice that.